# Tic Tac Toe Game DeclareWinner

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with the tic tac toe game I am coding. When New Game is hit under file menu, after a game has already been won, all it takes is the user to place one X or O and the program declares a winner again. I am not sure why it is doing this. Here is a pastebin link to the code.

```
private bool DiaganolWin()
    {

        //checks for diaganol winner
        if ((a1.Text == b2.Text) && (b2.Text == c3.Text) && (!a1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;
        else if ((a3.Text == b2.Text) && (b2.Text == c1.Text) && (!c1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        if (there_is_a_winner == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post a *small* example which produces the problem you're having, not the entire application. Your link is 222 lines long, and I would bet the issue could be reproduced in 10. SO isn't a debugging service.

Comment: For instance, after a new game following a winning game, this will always come out true even after only one X has been placed on the board. I updated it with a smaller relevant piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to rewrite your method, it was too "noisy" :)

```
private bool DiaganolWin()
{
    //checks for diaganol winner
    if ((a1.Text == b2.Text) && (b2.Text == c3.Text) && (!a1.Enabled))
        return true;

    if ((a3.Text == b2.Text) && (b2.Text == c1.Text) && (!c1.Enabled))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

To answer your questions - when you create a new game, have you reset all your variables? You're probably just running into an old state somewhere outside of the method you gave as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example of code. Mine did feel pretty cluttered. I am extremely new so I have difficulty writing compact code. That change in code seems to have fixed the problem, so I will look at how your sample is set up, and extend it to the other methods I have. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: No problem - and don't forget to mark the answer as "answered" so others can benefit from it :)